# Android, запрос и проверка необходимых разрешений

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile-development

При запуске приложения мне нужно проверять что у него есть все необходимые для работы разрешения.
Это я делаю в onStart Activity следующим образом

```
try {
        val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
        Log.d(TAG, "SDK " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " App Permissions:")
        if (info.requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (p in info.requestedPermissions) {
                val grantResult = this.checkPermission(p, android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.myUid())
                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$p PERMISSION_GRANTED")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$p PERMISSION_DENIED: $grantResult")
                    val permissions = arrayOf(p)

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
                }
            }
        }
```

В LogCat я вижу что практически все разрешения есть, за исключением

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
```

По логике у меня должно в случае если нет разрешения, то должно появиться окно с запросом его. Однако окно не появляется.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но всё же - эти разрешения есть в манифесте? Т.к. если их нет, то запрос будет автоматически отклонён и диалог не покажется. Пока это единственная причина которую могу предположить.

Comment: use case запроса разрешений у вас неправильный - разрешения нужно запрашивать только тогда, когда юзеру нужен соответствующий функционал, ну то есть захотел узнать локацию - запрашиваем пермишен, а сразу чохом запрашивать все пермишены - аппу с таким паттерном просто не пустят на Google Play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код из вопроса действительно работает некорректно. Насколько я понимаю, не стоит запрашивать более одного разрешения одновременно. Во всяком случае, не таким образом.

На коленке написал код, на моем эмуляторе сработал:

```
companion object {
    private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}

private var listOfNonGrantedPermissions: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
    Log.d(TAG, "SDK " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " App Permissions:")
    info.requestedPermissions?.forEach {
        if (checkPermission(it, android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.myUid()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG,"$it PERMISSION_GRANTED")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"$it PERMISSION_DENIED")
            listOfNonGrantedPermissions.add(it)
        }
    }
    makeRequestForNotGrantedPermissions()
}

private fun makeRequestForNotGrantedPermissions(){
    if (listOfNonGrantedPermissions.isNotEmpty()){
        val nextPermission = arrayOf(listOfNonGrantedPermissions.first())
        listOfNonGrantedPermissions.removeAt(0)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            nextPermission,
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Granted") 
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"NOT Granted")
            }
            return makeRequestForNotGrantedPermissions()
        }
    }
}
```

Суть кода:

1. Создаем список всех разрешений, которые не выданы.
2. Вызываем функцию запроса разрешения.
3. Функция запрашивает одно разрешение, если есть еще не полученные.
4. Получив ответ от пользователя, снова вызываем функцию запроса разрешения.
5. Если для всех разрешения ответ пользователя получен - процесс прекращается.

Код приведен для примера и с целью натолкнуть на действительное решение, использовать его в конечном варианте приложения не советую!